# How to launch an external url (intel-xdk)

Tags: html, cordova, intel-xdk

I want to ask about a problem which occurs by launching an external url in the browser app.

Here is my code (in intel xdk)

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

<!-- IMPORTANT: Do not include a weinre script tag as part of your release builds! -->
<!-- Place your remote debugging (weinre) script URL from the Test tab here, if it does not work below -->
<!--   <script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#insertabiglongfunkynumberfromthexdkstesttab"></script>  -->

<!-- Recommended location for your JavaScript libraries -->
<!-- These library references (below) are just examples to give you the general idea... -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/mc/hammer.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/ft/fastclick.js"></script> -->


    <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>           <!-- for your event code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>      <!-- for your init code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>     <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->
<script type="application/javascript"> 
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){
            intel.xdk.device.launchExternal("http://webagate.com/demos/alia/smarty-mobile-tablet-website-template/new-1/");    
},false);

    </script> 
    </head>


<body>

    <!-- <script src="http://debug-software.intel.com/target/target-script-min.js#insertabiglongfunkynumberfromthexdkstesttab"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with inAppBrowser plugin

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed the initial "welcome screen"

Comment: i'm import iframe and src=my url, work on emulator but error network connection on my device !! any help

Answer (score 0):

Intel XDK Native is being depreciated instead start using Cordova builds. 
Select InAppBrowser Plugin and use the below code for hyperlinks.

```
<a href = '#' onclick=window.open('http://example.com','_blank','location=yes')>
```

For more options check the plugin's documentation.

Update:

Just add below code to your app.js or auto generated index_user_scripts.js

```
(function()
{
 "use strict";
 /*
hook up event handlers 
*/
function register_event_handlers()
{

window.open('http://example.com', '_blank');

}
document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
})();
```

Comment: it appear a white screan! , now i uploaded responsive design on domain host and want to framed it into app browser when user open .apk app open  it in app browser ..any help plz :(

Comment: thank you , it works but with url bar !! how can i hide this bar that is appear url domain in it !! and thnx again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line in config.xml to let the app lunch any external url: `<access origin="*" />`

ref: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html